# Salto entre Texbox en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un sistema relativamente simple, pero no e podido desarrollar una de las funciones principales.

Requiero que ciertos Texbox  al ingresar cierto valor ("1" o "0") pase al siguiente texbox de forma automática. tiene un formato de 2 columnas y 4 filas, anexo una imagen de ejemplo..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria el formato, la escritura es de derecha a izquierda y se escribe en ese orden, una ves se llene el Campo N° 1, con un valor de ("1" o "0") debe saltar al siguiente campo.

De antemano agradezco el apoyo que me puedan prestar..

Comment: No mucho, tengo muy poca experiencia en hltm o cualquier relación con desarrollo web..
Quiero aprender, y estoy intentando pasar una aplicación funcional de escritorio a web, para que sea mejor distribuida.
en escritorio la programe en Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que esto sea lo que necesites.
Para lo que tu llamas *textbox* estoy utilizando `<input type="number"` Tu puedes utilizar elementos `<textarea>` si así lo deseas. Estos elementos tienen in atributo `tabindex`

Por favor lea los comentarios en el código.

```js
//el array de los elementos con un atributo tabindex
let iry = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[tabindex]"));
//un array se elementos undefined para ordenar el iry por el tabindex
let ordenado = new Array(iry.length); //[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
//llena el array ordenado de elementos input. Los orderna por el valor del atributo tabindex
iry.forEach((t, i) => {
  let thisTabIndex = ~~t.getAttribute("tabindex");
  ordenado[thisTabIndex] = t;
});



ordenado.forEach((t, i) => {
  t.addEventListener("input", () => {
    // si el valor value de del elemento t es 0 o 1
    if (t.value == 0 || t.value == 1) {
        //salta al siguiente input
        ordenado[i + 1].focus();
     
    } else {//si el valor no es 0 o 1
      t.value = "";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input{width:2em; height:2em; border-radius:50%; margin:.2em}

div{display:flex; width:5em; flex-wrap:wrap; outline:solid; background:blue;}
div *:focus{background:gold;}

button{padding:.5em; margin:1em 1em 1em 0;}
```

```html
<div>

<input type="number" tabindex="2" />
<input type="number" tabindex="1" />
<input type="number" tabindex="4" />
<input type="number" tabindex="3" />
<input type="number" tabindex="6" />
<input type="number" tabindex="5" />
<input type="number" tabindex="8" />
<input type="number" tabindex="7" />
  
</div>

<button tabindex="9">OK</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias enxaneta, tu código funciono a la perfección, es exactamente lo que necesito..
Gracias a todos por el apoyo y el interés en el tema...